# How to do 'If statement' with an on click event list box in VBA/Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, onclick, listbox

I have a form with 3 questions. If the person answers yes to the first question, they then must pick something from my list box or type in their own answer. I have a button that they press at the end of answering all 3 questions that triggers this. Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Q1. Do you play video Games? Yes / No Option Group Box

Q2. What videos Games? List Box (Game1/Game2/Game3)

Q3. Other Game: Plain Text

I havent started working on adding in Q3 to the mix as I cant get it working with Q2.
Can anyone help me ?

Submit button Code

```
Private Sub Submit_Button_Click()
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Dim qdef AS DAO.QueryDef

        Dim Msg,Syle,Title,Help, Ctxt, Response,Mystring
        Msg="Confirm your choices?"
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style,Title)
        If Response=vbYes Then
                If isNull(Me.game_response.value)  and (Me.play_response)=1
                Then MsgBox "Please Pick a Game"
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

List box Code

```
Private Sub Games Click()
Dim MyDB AS DAO.Database
Dim qdef AS DAO.QueryDef
Dim VarItem As Variant
Dim lstItem As Control
Set lstItem as Me!Games

For Each varItem in lstItems.ItemsSelected
        If SelectedValues>"" Then
                SelectedValues=SelectedValues&"|" lstItem.ItemData(VarItem)
        Else 
             SelectValues=lstItems.ItemData(varItem)
        End If
Next varItem

Me!game_response=SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues in your `Submit_Button_Click()`. You need to store the MsgBox Yes/No click (response) into your `Response` variable, then you can use it in your `If()` to compare it with `vbYes`/`vbNo`.

Sample updates/fixes:

```
Private Sub Submit_Button_Click()

    Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim Response As Long

    Response = MsgBox("Confirm your choices?", vbYesNo)

    If Response = vbYes Then
        If isNull(Me.game_response.value) And (Me.play_response) = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please Pick a Game"
        End If
    End If
```

The line `If SelectedValues>"" Then` in `Games Click()` is also using the wrong comparison operator - change it to `<>` (not equal to, instead of `>` greater than).

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding, but it still doesnt work. The part about declaring the 'response' variable was helpful, I actually forgot to copy it over and will edit it.
I dont think I want to change the comparison operator, it works fine and I want to concatenate if its greater than 0..